# Combine activity and component diagram in PlantUML

Tags: plantuml

I want to show the relationship between activities and components (so that managers would understand :-)). Is it possible to achieve something like this in PlantUML?

[image]

Comment: Please provide an example. Did you look at `allowmixing` / `allow_mixing` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say if it was an activity or a state diagram.

[It's possible with a state diagram](https://plantuml.com/deployment-diagram#e75c1203eb5d242a) (however, the `hide empty description` won't work when you `allowmixing` for some reason -- it's a bug?):

```
@startuml
hide empty description
allowmixing

state A
state B
state C
A --> B
B --> C

component "Component" as Comp
B .right. Comp

@enduml
```

[image]